# MockMVC for a controller method with Path variable and Object

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I have the controller as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/controller")
public class FindValue {

@RequestMapping(path="{id}/Method", method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> setMethodValue (@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody FindRequest findRequest) {
```

How to call this method from Junit using mockMvc

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FindValue {
    @InjectMocks
    private FindValue mockFindValue;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testMethodValue() throws Exception {
        FindRequest findRequest = new FindRequest();
        findRequest.setValue("thevalue");

        mockMvc
            .perform(post("/v1/controller/{id}/Method", 1)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
            .content(asJsonString(findRequest))
            ).andExpect(status().isCreated());

    }
```

But this returns 404 error

Could someone pls help

Comment: I would have expected a NullPointerException, since mockMvc is never initialized. Is that your real code?

Answer (score 0):

you have root reuqest mapping for controller **/v1/controller** ,and mapping for resource "**{id}/Method**"

it test you create url that not mapped : 
"**/v1/controller/{id}/Method**"

I thinks it should be

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{id}/Method", method = POST)
```

and @JB Nizet +1